# Question about Rank-Nullity Theorem Proof

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand the proof except for the very last part that says that the argument also shows these vectors are distinct.

How exactly does the argument show this. I need this to be super detailed otherwise I will go crazy if I don't fgure it out. I'm ci fused about the very last two sentences.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Are you confused why the vectors in $S$ are linearly independent?

Comment: I get that part. Again. The last two sentences.

Comment: The part about distinct vectors at the end buddy.

Comment: Ah you mean those sentences at the top of your screenshot. This is a really trivial statement. If you have a bunch of vectors $w_1, \dots ,w_n$ which are linearly independent, then no two vectors can be the same. Indeed assume (without loss of generality) that $w_1=w_2$, then $w_1-w_2+\sum_{i=3}^n0w_i=0$ but not all coefficients are zero. Hence if two vector are equal, they must be linearly dependent.

Comment: But according to the definition of linear dependence this only applies to distinct vectors.

Comment: That is why are we using the phrase linear dependence  for vectors thsr are not distinct. It is not encompassed in the definition.

Comment: Personally, I think the definition in this textbook is stupid. You should be able to say that two equal vectors are linearly dependent (in fact they cannot be more dependent than this). 

The problem is that this textbook insists on calling a **set** of vectors dependent. You cannot have repeated elements in a set and thus that definition cannot encompass repeated vectors. 

It's better to avoid sets altogether in these definitions and just define when a 'collection' of vectors is (in)dependent. Then all these pathological issues are resolved.

Comment: I assumed that the vectors were not distinct.  Then showed the vectors must have the property that the coefficients of the linear combination are zero to reach a contradiction since we can clearly find a non-trivial representing of the zero vector . Linear dependence or independce are meaningless here. By contradiction. , the vectors must be distinct. I get stuck with these kind of things in books, I just can't let go of the inconsistencies.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are confused as to how they show the vectors in $S=\{T(v_{k+1}), \dots,T(v_{n})\}$ to be linearly independent.

To show that $S$ is linearly independent, assume that $\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jT(v_j)=0$. We need to show that each $b_j$ is zero. By linearity of $T$, we find that $$T(\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j)=\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jT(v_j)=0.$$
Hence $\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j\in \ker(T)=N(T)$. By construction, we have a basis $\{v_1, \dots ,v_n\}$ of $V$ such that $\{v_1, \dots , v_k\}$ is a basis of $\ker(T)=N(T)$. Hence $\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j\in \ker(T)=N(T)$ implies that $\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j$ can be written as $$\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j=\sum_{i=1}^kc_iv_i.$$
Rewriting we get that $$\sum_{j=k+1}^nb_jv_j-\sum_{i=1}^kc_iv_i=0.$$ Looking at the last expression, this precisely is a linear combination of the vectors $\{v_1, \dots ,v_n\}$ which is zero. Since $\{v_1, \dots ,v_n\}$ is a basis, the only such combination is the zero combination. It follows that all coefficients (thus all $b_j$ and all $c_i$) are zero. In particular, the $b_j$'s are zero as required.